# MySQL Connector for C- Connect to remote database

Tags: c, mysql-connector

I'm using MySQL Connector (for C) to attempt to connect to a remote database. However, my code fails to instantiate a connection to a remote database. Here's the code

```
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    char *server = "192.168.1.114";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "PASSWORD_STUB"; /* set me first */
    char *database = "tmp";
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
                            user, password, database, 3306, NULL, 0)) {
       printf("ERROR CODE %u: %s", mysql_errno(conn),mysql_error(conn) );

    }else{
       printf("Connected..");
    }
```

The output from the error is

```
ERROR CODE 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.100' (using password: YES)
```

Am I attempting to connect to the server correctly? The IP in the error code is the IP of my machine NOT the IP of the remote host.

Comment: In order to connect to the remote `mysqld`, it must have enabled listening on port `3306` and must **NOT** have `skip-networking` uncommented in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. You will also want to check if `root` is prohibited from connecting remotely.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to cause the access failure, take a look at the link below, it provides some debug mechanism:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard part of locking down the database to not allow root remote access.

From the command line try "mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.1.114"

If that fails, try using another user other than root.

You must get the command line login working remotely before C can ever expect to connect remotely.